# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Huffman (wrong name: p3/Huffman)

Tags: java, eclipse, package, classpath

I am not sure how to fix this but I think it's rather a classpath error. I need to know where to run the following command if this is my file structure:

```
monas-mbp:p3 mona$ java Huffman c p3code.txt p3input.txt p3output.tx
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Huffman (wrong name: p3/Huffman)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Well, I already copied the Huffman.class from the following path actually to the current directory which is `/Users/mona/java/p3/src/p3` using

```
cp /Users/mona/java/p3/bin/p3/Huffman.class Huffman.class
```

so here's what I have in Eclipse. I created project p3 and then it automatically created package p3 while previously it used to create `default package`.
[image]

Any idea what's the fix? Also why it didn't create the `default package` automatically like always?

[UPDATE]Well, I didn't expect to receive such confusing answers specially because both project name as well as the automatically package name is p3. Can you please be more elaborate and detailed about your answers? Here's the structure created by Eclipse in my computer:
[image]

Also when I run the command in bin/p3 I get this result:

```
monas-mbp:p3 mona$ pwd
/Users/mona/java/p3/bin/p3
monas-mbp:p3 mona$ java Huffman c p3code.txt p3input.txt p3output.tx
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Huffman (wrong name: p3/Huffman)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I already copied the Huffman.class from the following path actually to the current directory which is /Users/mona/java/p3/src/p3 using
>
> `cp /Users/mona/java/p3/bin/p3/Huffman.class Huffman.class`

now execute java from parent directory of `p3` instead from `p3`, if you have copied it to current directory then execute following set of commands

```
 mkdir p3
 mv Huffman.class p3/
 java p3.Huffman c p3code.txt p3input.txt p3output.tx
```

so structure should be relative to current directory

```
p3
\
 |
 |
 ------Huffman.class
```

<sub>**note:** you are using eclipse to write code why not launch from it as well</sub>

Comment: this is a vague answer to me as I have two p3. Can you show it using real commands and path?

Comment: In which path should I write this command? java p3.Huffman c p3code.txt p3input.txt p3output.tx can you give me the absolute path?

Comment: can you please see the UPDATE in my question? Your update just confuses me!

Comment: goto `cd p3/bin` and then `java p3.Huffman and other parameters`  http://awesomescreenshot.com/06337w0619

Answer (score 1):

> it automatically created package p3 while previously it used to
>   create default package.

Huffman class must have a package declaration as p3. So when you have copied the file in eclipse project, eclipse either had asked you to move the file to p3 package or remove the package declaration from file.

Depending whether other files(Heap,HeapSandBox etc) in your project need to be p3 project or not, you may have to move the files.

To run your Huffman class, you need to use `package.classname`.

```
java p3.Huffman -cp p3code.txt p3input.txt p3output.tx
```

Comment: all of the files in p3 project automatically have `package p3`

Comment: In which path should I write this command? `java p3.Huffman c p3code.txt p3input.txt p3output.tx` can you give me the absolute path?

Comment: Go to directory contaning c3 and run java command from there. Don't go inside c3.